# Do any POSIX functions or glibc extensions implement a breadth-first file tree walk?

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, inotify, breadth-first-search

I am writing a daemon that utilizes inotify to monitor file access and it is critical that I don't miss anything on a recursive search. I found [this interesting idea](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/dashboard-hackers/2004-October/msg00022.html) and have begun to implement it.

ftw() and ftw64() do not use a breadth-first algorithm, its more "pre-order". nftw() gives me the option of depth-first, but I'm worried about races in upper leaves.

I'm hoping that I'm missing something, perhaps a GNU extension? Or am I just looking at implementing my own with type safe call backs (something I'd really rather not do) ?

Or, is my understanding of the advantages of breadth-first over depth-first erroneous for this type of application?

Comment: You probably don't need this any more but I implemented a breadth-first variant of nftw(3): https://github.com/tavianator/bfs/blob/master/bftw.c

Comment: @TavianBarnes That looks quite good and very self-contained, perhaps consider sending it to [CCAN](http://ccodearchive.net/)? In this particular instance, I just worked around the depth-first behavior as a limitation, I'm going to revisit that code now :)

Comment: Huh, TIL about CCAN.  I'll think about uploading it after I make a few changes and write some tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the spec for '[nftw()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)', the FTW_DEPTH flag does a post-order (depth first) traversal, visiting the sub-directories before visiting the directory node.

I don't think any of the standard algorithms do a breadth-first search.

Presumably, you should write a bfftw() based on the nftw() interface.  Note that you have to queue the items to be visited recursively (directories) while doing the scan.